Unable to Dynamically Access custom field on SObject Records in Salesforce
I am working with SObject records in Salesforce, specifically with QuoteLineItem objects, which are not enabled by default in our Salesforce environment. Instead of querying QuoteLineItem directly, I am retrieving records dynamically using SObject.
List<SObject> quoteLineItemList = (List<SObject>)odr.getSObjects('QuoteLineItems');

The problem I am facing is that I need to update the field SentinelEMSDEV__LineItemEID__c on QuoteLineItem records. Although I am able to retrieve QuoteLineItem records as SObject and check their Id fields, I am struggling to access the SentinelEMSDEV__LineItemEID__c field using dynamic methods.
for (SObject qli : quoteLineItemList) {
    System.debug('qli Object: ' + qli)

Here is the log for qli Object:

qli Object: QuoteLineItem:{QuoteId=0Q0J2000000oMXXKA2, Id=0QLJ2000000fyYOOAY, Quantity=1.00, Product2Id=01t5h00000BwAl0AAF}

The qli object only contains the fields QuoteId, Id, Quantity, and Product2Id. The SentinelEMSDEV__LineItemEID__c field is not visible in this log output. I need to dynamically access this field and update it based on certain conditions.
How to ensure the SentinelEMSDEV__LineItemEID__c field is included in the dynamically retrieved SObject records?

The "community" tag is meant to be used for a specific feature of Salesforce (community sites/experience sites). Since this question isn't about that, the tag should not be used.

You should look at the getSObjects() method of the class that's used as the type of your odr variable.

Here is my update on my post,
The problem is with using getSObjects() method , it restricted to retrieve some of main standard fields like Ids..etc. so that I followed the DataBase.Query(String), where String is
'SELECT Id, LineItemEID__c FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE QuoteId = :quoid WITH USER_MODE';

Now able to retrieve required fields from QuoteLineItem...
Thanks..
